# Is there a way to create a JavaScript date instance from an ISO 8601 date which works in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, date

When I try to create a JavaScript date instance from an ISO 8601 date using FireFox (and IE) I get "Invalid Date":

```
var d = new Date('2015-05-05Z');
alert(d); // Invalid Date
```

But things work OK in Chrome:

```
var d = new Date('2015-05-05Z');
alert(d); // Tue May 05 2015 01:00:00 GMT +0100 (BST)
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/z50LL4he/

Is there a way to create a JavaScript date instance from an ISO 8601 date that works in FireFox? Please note, I'm trying to do this without using a library such as momentjs.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: That's not a valid date according to [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). What makes you think `'2015-05-05Z'` is a valid ISO 8601 date? And why do you need to avoid moment.js?

Comment: @MattBall agreed. The `Z` is part of the **time** spec. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Thanks guys for the heads up about the Z. It's something that I'm getting back in my JSON after an API call I'm making. I'll let the API provider know

Comment: Is it an API that you own? Do you know why it's producing non-standard output?

Comment: @henrywright might want to make a note of that in your question

Comment: No idea, it's the Met Office's DataPoint API. The product I'm using is the daily site-specific weather forecast

Comment: @MattBall I have no reason to avoid moment.js - have used it in the past and it's great. My interest was in understanding the problem and trying to resolve myself (with the help of you guys of course :) )

Comment: are you able to request the date from the API in another format?

Comment: @MichaelHamilton I can put in a request, referencing the spec, but I doubt anything will happen quickly. I worked for the UK Civil Service for 5 years and nothing happens quickly hehe :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Z" at the end of your date string is a time zone designator.  Because you aren't providing a time but a date and a timezone, it is causing the error in some browsers - **this is not a valid ISO 8601 date**.

Since it seems the Chrome/Safari will actually return a usable date and Firefox/IE doesn't, we can at least setup some error handling to detect if the date was output correctly and handle accordingly.

In FireFox, if we pass the invalid date string into the `isNaN()` function, it returns `true`.  Knowing that we can say something like:

```
if(isNaN(date)){
    //handle the error appropriately
}
else{
    //carry on like nothing happened
}
```

Comment: From the spec (link in the comments above) is : "The value of an absent time zone offset is Z”. So, could the date be valid after all? Where the Z just represents an absent time zone offset?

Comment: @henrywright The Z stand for "Zulu Time" or UTC, so the "Z" is directly related to having a time, it has no relation to date.  "Z" signifies that the time is not local time but in UTC.  If there is no "Z" present in the time then it is assumed to be local time

Answer (score 3):

My browser *(Safari)* and possible others don't seem to like the `Z` at the end, it designates the Timezone instead of the actual time. You can trim it off *(Trims all letters from the end of the string)*:

```
var dateString = '2015-05-05Z'.replace(/[A-Za-z]+$/, ''),
    date       = new Date(dateString);
```

Comment: Or save yourself the trouble and not write the Z in the first place `var dateString = '2015-05-05'`

Comment: @MichaelHamilton He might be getting the date from a server, or another source. *OP seems to be getting it from an API's JSON*

Comment: I agree, in that case good point.  But if he's just assigning it to a variable, no need to trim the string, just don't write the character :)

Comment: Yeah, it's part of a JSON response I'm getting from an API call (Specifically, to UK Met Office's DataPoint service if you're interested).

Comment: @henrywright, sounds like bad data :)
in that case the suggestion to chop it off is perfectly valid

Answer (score 2):

If you expect date strings to have the form you present, you can convert them to ISO by adding the time (midnight GMT).

If you pass an actual ISO string (or any other correctly formatted date string) it will make a date without changing anything.

It will return 'Invalid Date' for invalid strings.

```
function almostISO(s){
    return new Date(s.replace(/(\d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d)Z/, '$1T00:00:00Z'));
}

var d= '2015-05-05Z';

almostISO(d).toUTCString();
```

returned value: (String)>> Tue, 05 May 2015 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: Thanks for the solution I can see how it will be useful; however, in my particular case I'm not sure adding a time is necessary because the value needs to represent the day as a whole; not a particular time during that day.

Comment: I forgot to +1 this. Done it now :)